# How is the Linux git repo related to other distribution git repos (such as Ubuntu)?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, git

I am trying to build a custom version of my Ubuntu kernel, and want to apply a patch that I see on the main Kernel tree.

I know that Ubuntu development happens in these repos:

git://git.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-kernel/ubuntu/+source//+git/

and the patch I want to apply was committed to the mainline kernel in mid-February of this year (2019):

https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=18736eef1213

Is there a way to tell where this commit was made and relate it somehow to the version of the Linux kernel being used in the Ubuntu distro I want to build (18.04)? If possible, I'd like to establish some kind of provenance when applying the patch to show where it was on the main kernel when I added it to my custom version.

Comment: Some distributions reuse Linux kernel version number but with some additional patches. Hence it is difficult, just with the kernel number to see exactly what is included or not. Normally distributions package both the compiled kernel and the sources used. Hence if you study the sources you can find out what is in the kernel or not.

Answer (score 0):

When I look in the list of [kernel updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes/ChangeSummary/18.04.2#Kernel_and_Hardware_support_updates) included in the latest LTS Ubuntu, 18.04.2, I do not see that particular item.

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/ lists kernels; http://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu explains how to add a later kernel if you find a kernel which has your commit.